# Возникновение дублей в bd при удалении пробела с лева

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Нашел небольшую ошибку в базе данных, как оказалось она намного больше чем я думал. В общем стал удалять пробел с лева в столбще "name" это поле является уникальным при удалении UPDATE `products` SET `name` = LTRIM( `name` ) мускул начал выдавать ошибки о дублях, в ручную потратил добрый час на удаление но с учетом что в базе больше 100 000 записей  это как мертвому припарка. Подскажите как можно этот процесс немного ускорить?
[image: Кусок моей bd]

Comment: А никак. Серверу пофиг. Это твоя забота - дополнить алгоритм либо методикой выбора (какую запись оставить, а какую удалить), либо методикой переименования (чтобы они перестали быть дубликатами). И спрашивать кого-либо бесполезно - нужно понимать смысл хранимых в таблице данных.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать копию таблицы с данными, очистить исходную таблицу и перегнать данные из копии с учётом удалённых пробелов.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `products` (`id`, `name`, ....)
SELECT `id`, TRIM(`name`), .... FROM `products_tmp` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Обратная сортировка для того, чтобы в конечный набор попали товары, которые добавлялись последними, так как они скорее всего содержат более актуальную информацию, чем старые копии с меньшим id.